# Get ViewModel ViewModelProvider.Factory and Application Context

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I am extending AndroidViewModel to get an application context in my ViewModel but Now I also want to pass some parameters to my ViewModel.
After some google search, I came to know that I can use ViewModelProvider.Factory to get Parametrized constructor of my MyViewModel but how to get an application context.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need an `Application` in `ViewModel.Factory` to instantiate an `AndroidViewModel`.

Ways to achieve this

- if you are instantiating the ViewModel in your Activity/Fragment then do `getApplicationContext()` and cast it as `Application`. If in fragment you can get the hosting Activity and get Application from it.

```
// Kotlin code
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,
                ViewModel.Factory(activity?.application!!, param1, param2)) // from an fragment onViewCreated()
```

- if your app has an `Application` class expose an method to get an application instance.

```
// JAVA code
public static Application getApp() {
        return YourApplication.instance; // instance will be an static field in Application class
    }
```

Comment: Can we use **androidx.activity.app.viewModels**?

Answer (score 0):

From your activity you can use:

Kotlin:

```
applicationContext
```

Java:

```
getApplication().getApplicationContext()
```